# How to change number of partitions, deleting all state is OK

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

Everything says you cannot, but only because Service Fabric can't move the state from the old partitions to the new ones. At this stage, I'm fine with downtime, and throwing out all the existing state and starting over.

Shouldn't un-installing and re-installing the Application work, or do I need to actually delete all the actor instances first?